# Using a DRF JSONField as a Serializer

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework

I have a custom `JSONField` which I would like to use as a serializer. Serializers provide a bunch of extra functionality that you don't get with a Field. Serializers are Fields but not the other way around.

As an example, consider a field which has some complex dynamic data and needs to be validated manually:

```py
from rest_framework.serializers import JSONField, Serializer


class MetadataField(JSONField):
    def to_internal_value(self, raw_data):
        data = super().to_internal_value(raw_data)

        # lengthy validation logic which is calling other methods on the class

        return data

class ItemSerializer(Serializer):
    metadata = MetadataField()
```

To keep this field reusable and to prevent bloating the `ItemSerializer` class we move the logic out into its own `MetadataField`. However, as a consequence, we no longer have access to things like `self.instance`, nor can we directly instantiate this class like a serializer and pass it some data.

Generating a dynamic schema is not an option, and I would like if at all possible to keep the validation logic out of `ItemSerializer`.